# Completely disable GNOME desktop right click

Tags: gnome

I want to completely disable GNOME desktop right click so when I right click on desktop, nothing show up.
The only thing I found was

```
/org/gnome/desktop/background/show-desktop-icons
```

and it only shows or hide the desktop icons. and seems that's not related to what I want.

Is there any extension or config to completely disable right click on GNOME desktop?

by disabling right click on GNOME desktop I mean when I right click on desktop I don't want to have any of these menus:

[image: GNOME right click menu]

[image: GNOME right click menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the gnome shell source code: [backgroundMenu](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/master/js/ui/backgroundMenu.js#L34) and [popupMenu](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/master/js/ui/popupMenu.js#L885).

I successfully disable background menu by using gnome-shell extension. Please do the following steps:

- Download my [gnome-shell-extension](https://github.com/chap-wong/gnome-shell-extension-disable-background-menu).
- Place the `metadata.json` and `extension.js` to `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/disable-background-menu@git.wongwanchap.mo/` (create the folder if necessary)
- Restart the gnome-shell by logout and login again.
- open `tweaks` tool and go to extension and find `Disable background menu` extension and enable it.

I am not a expert, I have just recently learned about gnome-shell, and this is my first extension. (It is not even published to gnome-shell community yet.), currently it only works when `dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/background/show-desktop-icons false`.

For the other case, you need to do the same for nautilus menu.

Comment: Please release it on GNOME extension website.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the above GNOME Extensions code works with GDM 3.28.2 on removing the GNOME3 right-click menu (Fig 1)

The right-click menu in Fig 2 is driven by the nautilus-desktop. I had to hack it a little on CentOs 7 because nautilus-desktop is launched with a --force flag, which literally says "ignore GSetting preferences". Anyway, to work around this I had to issue the following:

kill $pid | nautilus-desktop -q

where $pid is the process ID of nautilus-desktop --force process.