# To disable rightclick on ubuntu desktop

Tags: mouse, desktop-environments, xmodmap

I using Ubuntu 20.04 and GNOME desktop manager for end users to access the remote based application. Due to some reason, I need to restrict the Right-Click access on Ubuntu desktop. I used xmodmap to restrict right click on Desktop using below document

[xmodmap to restrict mouse right click](https://www.dangtrinh.com/2013/11/xubuntu-disable-mouse-right-click.html)

When I execute below command, I can't right click on desktop as well my application.

```
xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 99"
```

However, I would like to restrict Right click access on Ubuntu Desktop only, not in application. Can any one please how to use xmodmap command to restrict right click access on Ubuntu desktop?

Comment: Hi, I'm using ubuntu 20.04 version and GNOME Desktop manager.

Comment: There may be better ways to achieve what you want. You could for one disable the desktop icons, and thus a bunch of right-click options.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Completely disable GNOME desktop right click](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185390/completely-disable-gnome-desktop-right-click)

Comment: I followed this document https://askubuntu.com/questions/195503/how-to-disable-right-click-in-nautilus

Comment: Its working. However, its denying right click on application too. I would like to disable right click on desktop only.

Comment: When  i execute xmodmap -e 'pointer 1 2 99', its disabled right system-wide. However, I would like to disable right click on desktop, not in applications. Can any one please help me?

Comment: Any updates on this?